# Qué tipo de licencias de software existen para un código abierto pero que impida pueda ser modificado y redistribuido?

Tags: licencias

Existe algún tipo de licencia de software para un programa (javascript y solidity) que no está ofuscado (para ganar la confianza del usuario) pero que no deseo que sea copiado, ni redistribuido, ni forkeado, ni usado con otro nombre, etc..?

Estoy leyendo sobre las licencias MIT y GNU GLP pero todas permiten el forkeado y uso paralelo aunque exijan mención al original.

Gracias

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 2):

Los derechos de autor se aplican sobre el trabajo realizado, incluso si se publica bajo una licencia de código abierto. Las leyes de derechos de autor son las que permiten al autor del trabajo elegir si desea poder publicarlo bajo una licencia de código abierto. Incluso si su software se publica bajo una licencia de código abierto, alguien aún tiene sus derechos de autor (o quizás diferentes personas para diferentes piezas si ha aceptado contribuciones externas sin un acuerdo).

No encontrará una licencia de código abierto que impida la copia o la redistribución. Como documentación estos son algunos de los atributos fundamentales para una licencia de código abierto, según lo definido por OSI en [The Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd), así como por la FSF en su [definición de software libre](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

Deberá encontrar un tipo de licencia diferente, que no sea una licencia de software libre o una licencia de código abierto, si es que desea proporcionar su código fuente a los clientes o usuarios mientras los esta limitando a lo que pueden hacer con ese código fuente.

Comment: Gracias. Pensaba que código abierto simplemente significaba que no estaba encriptado. Había pensado en una licencia Creative Commons (CC BY-NC-ND 4.0)  Qué piensas?

Comment: @JTConsulta Las licencias Creative Commons no se recomiendan para el uso del software, te invito a leer el siguiente [articulo](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) donde no se recomienda

Comment: @JTConsulta las licencias de Creative Commons no son apropiadas para software ya que a diferencia de medios como ilustraciones, fotografias, musica, etc el software de codigo abirto se distribuyen dos cosas: la fuente y el binario o resultado final.

Las licencias de software toman en cuenta estas dos componentes del software en la licencia mientras que Creative Commons no.

Comment: No hay traducción al español pero puedes checar lo que dice Creative Commons sobre usar licencias de CC para Software aca: https://creativecommons.org/faq/?lang=es#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel Muchas gracias. Entre las licencias de software existentes, alguna se ajusta a que aunque deje el código sin ofuscar para demostrar buena fe, no sea permitida su copia, modificación y redistribución? Mi código está en javascript y solidity. Gracias

Comment: @JohnDoe   Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perdonar la confusión pero es que no parece haber una licencia que impida la modificación y redistribución de mi código..? https://choosealicense.com/licenses/

Comment: Eso no sería código abierto, te invito a conocer la definición de OSI y las 4 libertades esenciales de FSF

Comment: @JTConsulta No estoy seguro si verdaderamente existe una licencia que impida lo que buscas. Estoy más familiarizado con las licencias de código abierto. No me sorprendería que exista algo como lo que buscas, pero no puedo pensar en uno sin pensarlo dos veces. También puede consultar a un abogado que se especialice en este campo, para asegurarse de que la licencia se mantenga vigente en caso de que sea impugnada.